# Find Probability that even numbered face occurs odd number of times

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus, binomial-theorem

A Die  is tossed $2n+1$ times.  Find Probability that even numbered face occurs odd number of times

First i assumed let $a,b,c,d,e,f$ be number of times $1$ occurred, $2$ occurred and so on $6$ occurred respectively. Then we have

$$a+b+c+d+e+f=2n+1$$ is a linear equation where variables are non negative integers.

So number of non negative integer solutions of above is $\binom{2n+6}{5}$

But $b$, $d$ and $f$ should be odd. So let $b=2x+1$, $d=2y+1$ and $f=2z+1$ where $x,y,z$ are non negative integers.

so we get

$$a+2x+c+2y+e+2z=2n-2$$ which is possible in the following two cases

Case $1.$ $a,c,e$ are all even so let $a=2m+1$, $c=2q+1$ and $e=2r+1$ we get

$$m+x+q+y+r+z=n-1$$ so number of solutions is $\binom{n+4}{5}$

Case $2.$ Exactly two of $a,c,e$ are odd and other is even which can be possible in 3 ways.

So let $a=2m+1$, $c=2q+1$, $e=2r$ we get

$$m+x+q+y+r+z=n-2$$

Number of solutions is $3 \times \binom{n+3}{5}$

Hence Probability is

$$P(A)=\frac{\binom{n+4}{5}+3\binom{n+3}{5}}{\binom{2n+6}{5}}$$

Is my approach fine?

Comment: Even number and odd number are symmetric, so each has 0.5 chance to occur, so it is just like a coin toss

Comment: @lion: that is the probability that *the count for all* even-digit faces equals an odd number, not the probability that the *count for each* even-digit face *all* equal odd numbers.  It is not clear which the original question meant, but the poster appears to be attempting to find the latter.

Comment: There are $6^{2n+1}$ *equally* probable outcomes for rolling $2n+1$ six-sided die, so this *stars-and-bars* approach is *not* going to weight the events correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let us simplify the problem: the probability of an even face is 1/2, so is the probability of an odd face. The problem is therefore equivalent to a number of coin tosses of a fair coin, with even/odd faces corresponding to heads/tails.

Define the events $E$: the number of heads is even and $F$: the number of tails is even. On the one hand, heads and tails are perfectly interchangeable, therefore
$$
P(E)=P(F).
$$
Moreover, given an odd number of trials, either the number of heads is even or the number of tails is even, which implies
$$
P(E)+P(F)=1.
$$
You may then conclude that
$$
P(E)=P(F)=1/2.
$$

Therefore, the probability that even numbered face occurs odd number of times is 1/2.

Comment: awesome sir thanks a ton

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it should be noted that $0+3+0+1+0+1=5$ and $1+1+1+1+0+1=5$ are not equally likely. There are $\frac{5!}{3!}$ ways to get the first and $5!$ ways to get the second.

So counting these is not going to be a good approach.

Letting $P(x_2,x_4,x_6)=(3+x_2+x_4+x_6)^{2n+1}$, you then let:
 $$P_2(x_2,x_4,x_6)=\frac{1}{2}\left(P(x_2,x_4,x_6)-P(-x_2,x_4,x_6)\right),$$ this gives us the terms where $x_2$ has odd power.

Then $P_4(x_2,x_4,x_6)=\frac{1}{2}\left(P_2(x_2,x_4,x_6)-P_2(x_2,-x_4,x_6)\right)$ has the terms where $x_2$ and $x_4$ have odd powers.

Finally, $P_6(x_2,x_4,x_6)=\frac{1}{2}\left(P_4(x_2,x_4,x_6)-P_4(x_2,x_4,-x_6)\right)$ is the terms where all of $x_2,x_4,x_6$ have odd exponents.

Then the probability you want is:

$$\begin{align}\frac{P_6(1,1,1)}{6^{2n+1}}&=\frac{6^{2n+1}-3\cdot 4^{2n+1}+3\cdot 2^{2n+1}}{8\cdot 6^{2n+1}}\end{align}$$

---

Another approach is to use Markov processes, with states $0$ to $3$, which is the number of $2,4,6$ which have occurred an odd number of times. Start in state $0$ and you get a transition matrix:

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}&0&0\\
\frac{1}{6}&\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{3}&0\\
0&\frac{1}{3}&\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{6}\\
0&0&\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}
\end{pmatrix}$$

And the probability you want is $$\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0&1\end{pmatrix}A^{2n+1}\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}$$

Diagonalizing gives eigenvalues of $A$ equal to $0,\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3},1$, and the same probability as above.

Answer (score 1):

Even and odd faces both occur with a proabability of $\frac{1}{2}$. The probability of attaining an odd number of evens is
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{i=0}^{n} \binom{2n+1}{2i+1} \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^{2n+1}
\end{eqnarray*}
and an even number of odd faces is
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{i=0}^{n} \binom{2n+1}{2i} \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^{2n+1}
\end{eqnarray*}
Now note that these two sums are equal by the symmetry of the binomial coefficients so they are both $\color{red}{\frac{1}{2}}$.

Comment: but you are not couting how many times the face $2$ occurs, $4$ occurs an d $6$ occurs. Will it not matter?

Comment: That is the probability that $2\nmid (b+d+f)$.  The OP was trying to find the probability that $~2\nmid b~$, $2\nmid d$, and $2\nmid f$.

Comment: @Umeshshankar It depends on what the original question asked.  It is not clear from your post.

Comment: @GrahamKemp My understanding is ... Even numbered faces occurring an odd number of times.

Comment: Yes that is my question like suppose if die is tossed 7 times, Then one possibility is $2$ occurred one time, $4$ occurred  three times and $6$ occurred three times OR $2$ occurs one time , $4$ occurs one times, $6$ occurs three times and remaining two are odd faces.